How did Chasles use his parabola to draw normals from a given point P to an ellipse in the Euclidean plane?
If we are given (in a Euclidean plane) an ellipse $c$ and a point P, the normals from P to the ellipse can be determined by drawing the Appollonian hyberbola $h$ associated to P and intersect it with the ellipse. The intersection points are those points on $c$, whose normals meet P, i.e. $h$ intersects $c$ in the basepoints (pedal points) of P on $c$
Reportedly (see e.g. Glaeser/Stachel/Odehnal: The Universe of Conics, chap. 7), Chasles used a parabola instead of a hyperbola, and it seems to me, that Chasles the "constructed" tangents common to the ellipse and the parabola.
$c$, the given point in the plane is P. $c_1$ is the ellipse through P confocal with $c$. Apollonius' hyperbola is $h$ in yellow, and Chasles's parabola is $p$ in red. The two tangents common to the ellipse and the parabola are in red." />

Caption: Glaeser/Stachel/Odehnal, loc. cit., p.342. The given ellipse is $c$, the given point in the plane is P. $c_1$ is the
ellipse through P confocal with $c$. Apollonius' hyperbola is $h$ in
yellow, and Chasles's parabola is $p$ in red. The two tangents common
to the ellipse and the parabola are in red.

I do not see, how Chasles did his constructions and how he found common tangents. In my opinion, it is (a little bit) more difficult to construct common tangents to conics than to "draw" the intersections. In general, neither points of intersections nor common tangents can be "constructed".


Why is Chasles's parabola superior to Apollonius' hyperbola?

How did Chasles use his parabola to draw normals from the given point P to the ellipse $c$ in the Euclidean plane?

Did he draw the strophoid $s$, which is the pedal curve of $p$ with    respect to P, and is this strophoid easier "constructable" than Apollonius's hyperbola $h$?

Is there historic literature available, which clarifies Chasles's method and how he proceeded?



Thank you!

Woods, R. (1932). Some Conics with Names. In Proceedings of the Iowa Academy of Science (Vol. 39, No. 1, p. 197f.).

@GeorgEssl Thank you for that additional reference! Woods' publication (which I know) names the conics, but sadly doesn't explain how Chasles used the parabola named after him to determine the footpoints of P on the ellipse c, i.e. the common tangents of c and p.

Notice section (2) in Woods. It says "Let P be any point in the plane of the ellipse." Following Woods's instructions some choices are not determined but arbitrary, this includes the choice of conic (ellipse is chosen) and the point P. As Woods later explains there are exceptional tangent lines on the conic, related to P. Understanding the mathematics of this construction should be directed at SE:Mathematics or SE:MO as it is not a question of history.
